# python - criar uma lista a partir de múltiplos input

Tags: python

preciso fazer um código que receba input de usuários (quantidade indefinida) e pare quando o input for zero. depois, preciso que as entradas recebidas até o zero sejam transformados numa lista, que será usada posteriormente para uma comparação dos valores. segue o que tentei fazer e que obviamente não deu certo, ou eu não estaria aqui... quando coloco o zero, o código para, mas me dá como saída [0], em vez da lista com os valores anteriores.

PS: sou mto, mto, mto iniciante. perdão se a pergunta for idiota. tentei postar antes e minha pergunta foi removida.

```
entradas = input()
while entradas != '0':
  entradas = input()
  if entradas == '0': 
    break

valores = entradas.split()
lista_entradas = [int(valor) for valor in valores]
print(lista_entradas)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Obs: Nenhuma dúvida é idiota. Todas são igualmente válidas. Não sinta vergonha de fazê-las. :)

Agora partindo para o código, como você mesmo disse, precisa desses dados em uma lista. Neste trecho do programa:

```
entradas = input()
```

Você está criando uma variável simples, ou seja, uma variável que só pode armazenar uma informação por vez.

Obs: Sempre determine que tipo de entrada se espera de um input(). Por exemplo:

```
int(input())
float(input())
str(input())
```

Para quando deseja receber números inteiros, números com vírgula ou textos, respectivamente. Você pode aprender mais sobre isso pesquisando sobre Tipos Primitivos.

Então, quando você cria o loop:

```
while entradas != '0':
  entradas = input()
  if entradas == '0': 
    break
```

Cada vez que o usuário insere uma informação nova, a antiga é apagada. O mesmo acontece quando ele digita 0 pela ordem em que o loop foi construído, sendo assim, a variável "entradas" recebe o valor 0, e só depois o loop é quebrado.

Então, como resolver isso? Bom, primeiro criaremos uma lista em Python, assim:

```
entradas = []
```

Você está informando o computador que a variável "entradas" é uma lista, ou seja, uma variável que pode guardar diversas informações. Para adicionar os inputs do usuário, podemos criar um loop, mas agora, impedindo que o 0 seja adicionado quando o usuário quiser encerrar o programa.

```
while True:
  entrada = int(input())
  if entrada == 0:
    break
  entradas.append(entrada)
```

O "while True" criará um loop infinito que só vai parar de pedir o input do usuário quando a variável "entrada" que criamos receber o valor 0. Para adicionar valores em uma lista utilizamos a função "append()". A linha:

```
entradas.append(entrada)
```

É responsável por adicionar o input do usuário à lista que criamos lá no começo do nosso programa e pode ser lida como "lista 'entradas' recebe o valor armazenado na variável 'entrada'". Adicionamos a condição:

```
if entrada == 0:
  break
```

Antes de adicionar o novo item à nossa lista pois assim ela impede que o 0 seja adicionado nela quando digitado.

As linhas:

```
valores = entradas.split()
lista_entradas = [int(valor) for valor in valores]
```

São desnecessárias.
A saida gerada por:

```
print(entradas)
```

Deve se parecer com isso:

```
[1, 142, 812, 32]
```

Solução completa:

```
entradas = []
while True:
  entrada = int(input())
  if entrada == 0:
    break
  entradas.append(entrada)
print(entradas)
```

Comment: mto obg pela ajuda e pelas explicações! me ajudou mto!